# Granting local adminstrator permissions to a user for executing a VBS script

Tags: vbscript, user-permissions

I am currently working on a LogOn VBScript which has to copy files from one destination to another. Before I start to copy I have to set 2 registry keys. One of them is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER and the other in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. I can write the registry key into HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but not into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE because of the permissions of the users. Next thing is that I have to read from a mapped shared folder (e. g. mapped to 'Z:'). If I run the script locally on my computer, I can get the mapped shared folder like this:

```
Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = 'Z:'")
```

But when I'm running the script as admin I can't get the mapped folder, but I can write to the registry. Is there any way I can do both tasks with one script?
I can't change the permissions and one requirement is that everything has to be done with one script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drives are mapped to user tokens. Limited and Admin are different tokens. So Z: won't be available if run as admin. So use unc `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: I realized it's not possible to solve this like it was desired. I didn't know enough about how user rights are granted and handled. Thank's for your response! :)